# Using objects to make state with AJAX functions as properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bootstrap 3.0 to display a tooltip (this example isn't specific to boot-strap) where the html inside the tooltip is fed from an AJAX call.  In the future I want to be able to use the same element to fire different AJAX calls (something like fire a different AJAX call if the shift+click was used).  To make that easy, I decided to use a `tooltipManager` object.  This object currently has two properties:

1. title: in bootstrap, this is the html represented when an element is hovered over
2. placement: the values for this are left,right,top,bottom

EDIT: I just got the program working, but I need to know WHY it's working because I tried something like this for hours and had nothing but bad luck.  Why is `setPlacement` able to return the correct value?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //in the future there will be n amount of these
        //each will have the ability to use different urls to make different AJAX calls (not implemented yet)
        var tooltipManager = {
            title: function () {
                //ajax code to get title from database
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "Service.asmx/GetDrugs",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //bootstrap uses the title attribute to set the html inside the tooltip
                        //here it's set to the results of the AJAX
                        $('#click').attr('title', data.d)
                                   .tooltip({
                                       trigger: 'click',
                                       html: false,
                                       //using the sizer function the tooltip is placed where it needs to be.
                                       placement: tooltipManager.placement.setPlacement(data.d)
                                       //it seems to me that it would be better design to call the tooltipManager
                                       //setPlacement function, but since it's an async request, it fails

                                   }).click();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log('failed: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                });

            },
            placement: {
                left: 'left',
                top: 'top',
                right: 'right',
                bottom: 'bottom',
                setPlacement: function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 4) {
                        return this.bottom;
                    }
                    else {
                        return this.right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $('#click').one('click', function () {
            //how can I pass the entire state of the object here, instead of invoking these methods one by one.
            tooltipManager.title();
        });
        //not sure if this is good design to have this not a property of the tooltipManager object
        //this works currently for placing the tooltip in the correct position
        function sizer(data) {
            if (data.length > 4) {
                return tooltipManager.placement.bottom
            }
            else {
                return tooltipManager.placement.right
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setPlacement` method returns the "correct" data because whatever `d` is in your data object you receive from `Service.asmx/GetDrugs` is compared to be greater than 4. If it is then it will set the tooltip placement of the `$('#click')` element to `bottom`, otherwise it will set it to `right`. You can check it out by sticking this code at the bottom of the page:

```
alert('this is 3 characters: ' + tooltipManager.placement.setPlacement('asd'));
alert('this is 5 characters: ' + tooltipManager.placement.setPlacement('asdfg'));
```

All that placement does is it `returns` the words "left","top","right", or "bottom" depending on what it's set to in the `placement` object. You can change that object to this and it will still work:

```
placement: {
    l: 'left',
    t: 'top',
    r: 'right',
    b: 'bottom',
    setPlacement: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 4) {
            return this.b;
        }
        else {
            return this.r;
        }
    }
}
```

The `setPlacement` method doesn't actually set anything. What does is your jQuery's `tooltip` method.

You can change up all of line 48 like this (you also had a typo):

```
$('#click').on('click', tooltipManager.title);
```

You can delete the sizer function as I don't see a use for it. Something like that should be a method of the tooltipManager object anyways. On the same subject, since `setPlacement` doesn't actually set anything, you should probably change it to `getPlacement` or `calcPlacement`. It's more semantic and will help other developers that come behind you.

I would personally redo the entire `tooltipManager.placement` object to show the actual data that would be unknown. As an example, why on Earth would you need a static object to tell you what the number 2 is? Same for the string `'bottom'`. `tooltipManager.placement.bottom` is the same thing as `'bottom'`. Here's how I would structure that:

```
var tooltipManager = {
    setTitle: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "Service.asmx/GetDrugs",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#click').attr('title', data.d)
                .tooltip({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: false,
                    placement: tooltipManager.setPlacement(data.d)
                }).click();
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.error('Failed tooltip request: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        });
    },
    setPlacement: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 4) {
            tooltipManager.placement = 'bottom';
            return 'bottom';
        } else {
            tooltipManager.placement = 'right';
            return 'right';
        }
    }
}

$('#click').on('click', tooltipManager.setTitle);
```

Note: I actually kept the `setPlacement` method, I just changed it so that it actually sets data. You can access the placement of the tooltip in javascript with `tooltipManager.placement` if you want. If you intend on having multiple tooltips you can just convert this all into a class. Also, I changed the `tooltipManager.title` method into `tooltipManager.setTitle` because it actually sets data.